# How can I display only the div I clicked in an array.map() element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, jsx

I have a page where it displays information about students, I'm currently using array.map() to show all students. There's a function in this page, where you can click in one student to show more info. I'm using an onClick function to display a component. But when you click the student, the component is displayed at all the other students. How can I identify that I clicked the student X and show just X's info, and not Y's and Z's too?

Here's the page:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BsFillCircleFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { FiSearch } from 'react-icons/fi';
import { IoIosArrowDropdown } from 'react-icons/io';

import * as colors from '../../config/colors';
import { Content, Search } from './styled';
import Title from '../../components/Subheader';
import DropInfo from '../../components/DropInfo';

export default function Relação() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(false);
  const [style, setStyle] = useState('drop');

  const handleDrop = (identifier) => {
    const newInfo = info;
    setInfo(!newInfo);
    console.log(identifier);

    const newStyle = style;
    switch (newStyle) {
      case 'drop':
        setStyle('drop-2');
        break;
      case 'drop-2':
        setStyle('drop');
        break;
      default:
        setStyle('drop');
        break;
    }
  };

  const alunos = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nome: 'Miguel Moreira Rodrigues',
      cpf: '000.000.000-00',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      nome: 'Miguel Moreira Rodrigues',
      cpf: '000.000.000-00',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Title
        nome="Relação de alunos"
      />
      <Search>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Digite sua busca" />
        <FiSearch size={30} className="lupa" />
      </Search>
      <Content>
        <div className="alunos">
          {alunos.map((aluno) => {
            if (info) {
              return (
                <>
                  <section>
                    <BsFillCircleFill size={24} color={colors.statusGreenColor} className="circle" />
                    <p>
                      {aluno.nome}
                      {' '}
                      CPF:
                      {' '}
                      {aluno.cpf}
                    </p>
                    <IoIosArrowDropdown
                      type="checkbox"
                      onClick={() => handleDrop(aluno.id)}
                      className={style}
                      size={24}
                    />
                  </section>
                  <DropInfo />
                </>
              );
            }

            return (
              <section>
                <BsFillCircleFill size={24} color={colors.statusGreenColor} className="circle" />
                <p>
                  {aluno.nome}
                  {' '}
                  CPF:
                  {' '}
                  {aluno.cpf}
                </p>
                <IoIosArrowDropdown type="checkbox" onClick={handleDrop} className={style} size={24} />
              </section>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </Content>
    </>
  );
}
```

And here's the component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Info } from './styled';

export default function DropInfo() {
  return (
    <Info className="drop-info">
      <div className="lado-1">
        <p>
          <strong>Nome</strong>
          {' '}
          Miguel Moreira Rodrigues
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
          <strong>CPF</strong>
          {' '}
          000.000.000-00
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
          <strong>RG</strong>
          {' '}
          0000000000.0
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
          <strong>Nascimento</strong>
          {' '}
          19/12/2005
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
          <strong>Igreja</strong>
          {' '}
          Adventista
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="lado-2">
        <p>
          <strong>Endereço</strong>
          {' '}
          Rua Jorge Brasilino, 217, Catolé
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
          <strong>Cidade/Estado</strong>
          {' '}
          Horizonte-CE
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
          <strong>Telefone</strong>
          {' '}
          (85) 9-9198-0673
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
          <strong>Status civil</strong>
          {' '}
          Solteiro
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
          <strong>Turma</strong>
          {' '}
          Professor Carlos
        </p>
      </div>
    </Info>
  );
}
```

To better explain my problem, here's what happening:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `id` to specify which of your items you want the info to show on, something like this should do work for ya

```js
export default function Relação() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(false);
  const [style, setStyle] = useState('drop');

  const handleDrop = (identifier) => {
    const newInfo = info === identifier ? false : identifier; // open a new one or close the current
    setInfo(newInfo);

    ...rest of the function
  };

  return (
    <>
     ...rest of the component
     {alunos.map((aluno) => {
       if (info === aluno.id) { // only show the info where the id matches
         return (
           <React.Fragment key={aluno.id}> // you will want a key
             <section>
               ...component stuff
               <IoIosArrowDropdown
                 type="checkbox"
                 onClick={() => handleDrop(aluno.id)}
                 className={style}
                 size={24}
               />
             </section>
             <DropInfo />
           </React.Fragment>
         );
       }

       return (
         <section key={aluno.id}> // also want a key here
           ...component stuff
           <IoIosArrowDropdown
             type="checkbox"
             onClick={() => handleDrop(aluno.id)} // updated this to pass the id
             className={style}
             size={24}
          />
         </section>
       );
     })}
     ...closeComponent
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I could use the same logic for these arrow icons, right? Because when I click one, all the arrows rotate together.

Comment: Yes, instead of having the style in state you would compute it for each item during the mapping

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are missing a key property

```
<div className="alunos">
          {alunos.map((aluno) => {
    …
    <section key={aluno.id}>
    …
```